# Animating a bone to turn 360° doesn't rotate correctly

Tags: animation, 3d-view, keyframes, graph-editor

I'm animating a character to do a 360° spin jump in midair but on the last frame of the spin he rotates the opposite direction instead

It basically does this

[image: Example]

I could make it work if I used a bunch of keyframes, but that's sloppy and makes the animation jittery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if you keyframe it in the 3D view it won't interpolate correctly because either it doesn't know in what direction it is supposed to go or *Quaternion* interpolation is messy, don't ask me why.

The easiest way to do it is to use the *N > Item > Transform* panel, switch *Quaternion* to *XYZ Euler*, and keyframe a rotation of 0/0/0° at frame 0, and 0/360/0° at frame X (I keyframed the bone in *Pose* mode, if you want to keyframe the armature in *Object* mode it will be 0/0/360°):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: FINALLY I got it figured out, thanks a bundle!

Comment: Also, use `locrotscale` instead of `visual locrotscale` otherwise it will take the shortest path to the keyframe when animating.